# Can I repartition the internal storage of my device to make space for apps?

Tags: internal-storage, partitions

I have a T-Mobile Concord and it has little memory (probably standard amount).  It is used up by applications that I don't use or don't need.  I would like to partition the OS so that I can increase the internal memory so I can download other apps or play games that I have downloaded.  Is this possible or am I just S.O.L.?

Answer (score 1):

Highly doubt if this can be done, even *if* it is feasible, it is *extremely risky* and could render the phone bricked!

Some handsets have the capability to resize the partitions used.

For example:

- The Zte Blade is one very good example that can enable through what's known as TPT transfer, where the `/system`, `/cache` and `/data` can be resized conveniently, albeit in a limited fixed way, such as 2Mb `/cache`, and 210Mb `/system`. See this example of the [alternative layouts](http://amphoras.co.uk/index.php/downloads/blade-tpts) that can be used for this handset.

The software used to achieve this, is not easy to find on the internet, known as, *testpoint*, although it does require specialized knowledge on how to use it, and does involve the risk of overwriting the IMEI number for this to work.

There is one for Qualcomm based handsets and is floating around on the internet.

Now, going back to T-Mobile Concord handset, not sure if there's one for specified handset concerned, as [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/t_mobile_concord-4949.php) indicates that this is a Broadcom chipset...

It might be best to dig around on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com) to see if anyone has achieved it.

If not, then take it as a no-go!